# What are differences between tree data structure and composite design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, tree, treeview

I'm designing a product category management feature for my project. Basically, a product category has got the following properties:

- ID
- Name
- Parent category
- Child categories

Now I want to display all product categories as a tree view on the UI. It looks like:

- Electric devices

  - Computer

    - Desktop
    - Laptop
    - Server
  - Smart phone
    ...
- Clothes

  - Men

    - Jean
    - Shirt
  - Women

    - Dress
- ...

Currently, I'm designing a class ProductCategory using tree data structure to represent the whole product category tree as below:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ProductCategory Parent {get;set;}
    public List<ProductCategory> Children {get;set;}
}
```

I don't know whether composite design pattern can apply to this case or not?

What are differences between tree data structure and composite design pattern?

Thanks

Tuan

Answer (score 0):

In the Composite Pattern, the purpose is to encapsulate the cardinality of the objects in use.  Or as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) says it:

> The composite pattern describes a group of objects that is treated the
>   same way as a single instance of the same type of object.

Your case does not appear related, except that the name "Composite" as an English word might connote something similar to a tree data structure.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But I really don't understand what are differences between tree data structure and composite design pattern. Could you please explain clearer?